# fatal error: module 'React' in AST file React-Native

Tags: react-native, expo

I am currently encountering the following errors.
I read this article but Error not resolved.
Error not resolved.

How can i Solve this error?

Version
"expo": "^49.0.22",

```
› Executing lottie-react-native Pods/lottie-react-native » Copy generated compatibility header
› Compiling Pods/Pods-second » Pods-second-dummy.m
› Packaging Pods/Pods-second » libPods-second.a
› Executing second » [CP] Check Pods Manifest.lock
› Executing second » Start Packager on http://localhost:8081
› Executing second » [Expo] Configure project
› Preparing second » Info.plist

❌  fatal error: module 'React' in AST file '/Users/CCCC/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/279GFH1YNK2VU/React-25OT4LWM2G0S4.pcm' (imported by AST file '/Users/CCCC/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/second-cbsqqrbsgngqeyfluleojeraabxk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders/second-Bridging-Header-swift_PPVHGG8EIN9I-clang_279GFH1YNK2VU.pch') is not defined in any loaded module map file; maybe you need to load '/Users/CCCC/Desktop/code/second/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-Core/React/React-Core.modulemap'?


› Compiling second » main.m
› Compiling second » second_vers.c
› Compiling second » AppDelegate.mm
› Linking   second » second
⚠️  ld: directory not found for option '-F/Users/komatsushota/Desktop/code/second/ios/../node_modules/react-native/React-Core'
› Generating debug second » second.app.dSYM
› Executing second » Bundle React Native code and images
› Executing second » [CP] Embed Pods Frameworks
› Executing second » [CP] Copy Pods Resources
› Signing   second » second.app
› Build Succeeded

› 1 error(s), and 1 warning(s)
```

That this error is resolved when yarn ios is run.